# Limit for a function of two arguments from its partial limits

Tags: real-analysis

I have a positive real-valued function of two positive arguments, f(d,e). The limit of f(d,e) as e goes to zero is positive, for each d fixed. The limit of f(d,e) as d goes to zero is zero, for each e fixed. The function f is monotone (non-decreasing) in each argument and bounded. Can I claim that there is a sequence d(e) going to zero as e goes to zero, such that the limit of f(d(e),e) as e goes to zero is positive? Intuitively, it looks like this should be true by choosing d(e) sufficiently slow, but how do I prove it? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Actually $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)=0$. To see this, fix $\epsilon>0$.

Consider $f(1,y)$ as $y\to 0$. The limit is $0$, so there exists $y_0$ such that $f(1,y_0)<\epsilon$. Now in the open rectangle with vertices $(0,0), (1,0), (1,y_0),(0,y_0)$ the function $f$ is always less than $f(1,y)$ (because the horizontal and vertical sections are decreasing) and so it is less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks. Does the joint limit to zero imply that doesn't exist a subsequence d(e) with the properties that I mentioned above? Actually, rather than an implication, what I am after is a characterization of my situation with subsequences indexed by e. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: If you only assume that the limits on vertical and horizontal lines are $0$ you can say nothing (it is not enough to even consider all the lines). Take for instance in $f(x,y)=1$ if $y=x^2$ and $0$ otherwise in $\{(x,y):x>0,y>0\}$. If I understand what you mean, in this case an example of sequence would be $(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n^2})$.

Comment: The vertical limit is zero but the horizontal is positive.

Comment: Sure, then take $f(x,y)=1$ if $y\geq x^2$ and $0$ otherwise.